# Sockets - how to?

Tags: android, sockets

I'm trying to make an application that sends a .tar file through a socket through android.

The idea is to make an adb forward tcp:8000 tcp:800; netstat -w 10 localhost:8000 > out.tar; on the computer end.

And then on the SmartPhone end I have the following code running:

```
Log.i(TAG, "Launching Socket");
Socket sk = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 8000);
Log.i(TAG, "Socket Launched");
TarOutputStream out = new TarOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(sk.getOutputStream()));
tarFolder(null, "/sdcard", out);
```

For some reason when trying to execute the code I get the error:

```
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 8000): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

I know the error is self-explanatory but I can't figure out how to fix it. Any clues?

Comment: Does your app have `INTERNET` permission set in the manifest?

Comment: Yes it does. The permission is set, although it is never asked in the application (should it ask it?)

Comment: If the error is self-explanatory why can't you figure it out? ECONNREFUSED only has one meaning. What's the question here?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured the error out.
Problem was that I thought I was redirecting the ports properly by using adb forward, but as I wanted to redirect a port from the phone to the computer what I had to use was adb reverse.